# How do I change my C-gear skin?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have 'Minccino' c-gear skin, in use, and now I got the 'Reshiram' c-gear skin, from the last event.

How can I switch between my C-gear skins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled the question so hopefully this is correct.

Log on to your pokemon global link account. On the bottom right corner of the screen there is a Red Coded DS with the word "Customize". Click that. Under the C-Gear skin simply click on the 'Reshiram' picture.

Comment: Hi @Samjus Thank you for your reply. I checked / tested it. It works fine. Thank you =)

Comment: You are very welcome :)